# Bug of Bash?? When setting of `$HISTIGNORE` ends with `SP`+`*` or `SP`+`?*`

Tags: ubuntu, bash, wsl2, git-for-windows

When setting of `$HISTIGNORE` ending with `SP`+`*` or `SP`+`?*`, lists of files in current folder will be concated to it's value.

No matter `extglob` is set or unset.

NG Example, (current folder has only one file 'do_music.sh'):

```
$ export HISTIGNORE="ls:ls *:history:history *:sudo *"
$ echo $HISTIGNORE
ls:ls *:history:history *:sudo do_music.sh
$
```

OK Example:

```
$ export HISTIGNORE="ls:ls *:history *:sudo *:history"
$ echo $HISTIGNORE
ls:ls *:history *:sudo *:history
$
```

Comment: OK.  Both `'` and `"` work fine. The following commands can be used to verify it's value. 1. `printenv HISTIGNORE` 2. `echo "$HISTIGNORE"` 3. `echo "${HISTIGNORE}"` 4. `env | grep HISTIGNORE`

Comment: Also, both example work fine, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**

As per my original answer, you need to use single quotes for the `*` to remain as is. If you do that, the variable `HISTIGNORE` will contain just the `*` and not the expansion. When you `echo`, you see the expansion happening, because the shell replaces `$HISTIGNORE` with a `*` and then substitutes with the file list.

<s>You can verify by running `env | grep HISTIGNORE` in both cases. In the `"`-case you will see `do_music.sh` there, in the `'`-case you will see the `*`.</s>

Also, you can try running the `export HISTIGNORE` line while in one directory, and the `echo` line while in another, you will see a difference depending on whether you use `'` or `"`

(I striked out the above part because it turns out to be false, both single and double quotes should work after all for your case, since `*` are not being substituted inside double quotes either).

**Update 3**

The reason you get the `echo` behavior is because of the order of substitutions in bash. According to the manual:

```
       The  order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and vari‐
       able expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-
       right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.
```

First happens the **parameter/variable** expansion (the `$HISTIGNORE` changes to `*`), and after that happens the **pathname** expansion (the `*` changes into the list of files).

**Original answer below**

When you execute the first line:

```
export HISTIGNORE="ls:ls *:history:history *:sudo *"
```

the shell already expands the last `*` to the list of files in your directory, that's why you are getting `do_music.sh` at that place.

If you happened to have a file named e.g. `bla:sudo`, then `*:sudo` would also get substituted by this. It does not, because no file matches that pattern.

To avoid this from happening, you have to use single quotes to avoid any `*` substitutions:

```
export HISTIGNORE='ls:ls *:history:history *:sudo *'
```

**Update**

Btw, there is nothing special about HISTIGNORE, this would happen for any variable definition, or for any command in that matter, if you have a `*` by itself somewhere within double quotes, it will be substituted by the list of files (not starting with `.`!) in the current directory (unless the current directory is empty, or only contains files starting with `.`, in which case the `*` will remain as is).

Comment: NO, I tested it both with `'` or `"`. Both test I got same result. I test it on bash of WSL2 Ububtu 22.04 and bash shell of 'git for windows'.

Comment: You are right - it also happens with single quotes! I stand corrected...

Comment: The `'` actually works, see my update, you still see the `do_music.sh` just because of the `echo`, but actually the `*` is saved internally in the variable.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.